# If a url is redirected to another, is there a way to use the original domain in php

Tags: php, redirect

Noob here! This is my first post - I apologise if it's been answered already.
I can't find anything in the search!

I have a number of sites in development and want to redirect them all to a single splash page for the company that owns them.

Is there a way to determine which url it was redirected from to allow different text and contact info to be called?

I can find lots of answers about using the current url - but not one that redirected to it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are you doing the initial redirections? One way of doing this is when you do the redirect pass in a get param that contains a unique id for each site and then do a check in your splash page and serve different assets based upon that get param.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?  Not guaranteed, but should work for most requests.

Comment: Psyco - The redirects were just done using the default destination from the host for ease   |   Kkinsey - I'll try that - thank you!

Comment: When you write those add on a query string so its like this 

http://www.domin.com?siteId={int}

Replacing {int} with a unique number for each redirected site. Then in your splash page get that param and do a check on it in your script to change the code. If you want me to submit an answer, give us your redirect blocks and ill modify them and get you started on the php.

Edit: Accidentally submitted.

Comment: Ahh ok - perfect. Then reference the id in the page script. That's much simpler. I have to admit, I need to do a lot more reading!  Thank you!   --- I've just seen your edit. I'm going to have a go - if I make an absolute mess I'll be back - and probably get voted down again for a stupid question :D

Comment: No problem, you may still want to put up your blocks and let me write the answer so this question can be closed though.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kkinsey said in the comments - The first approach I would take is starting with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Answer (score 0):

Using `Referer` will work *most of the time*. Some browsers don't send it.

Instead, add a `GET` parameter to your redirection URL:

```
header("Location: http://main-company.net/splash?from=".$website_id);
exit;
```

Then retrieve it on the main website, if set it will be the variable `$_GET['website_id']`.